# Not able to click on element in android mobile automation

Tags: mobile, automation, appium, appium-android

With Uiautomator not able to identify the element. I need to click on the button which is highlighted in blue color ( which is shown on image). Can someone help me how to click on the highlighted button. When I capture XMl using Uiautomator.. application is not pulling xml source for that button

[image]

Comment: please attach the xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to fetch xml hierarchy with uiautomator viewer, you can use [appium inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector) to get the xml layout of the application under test.